# Как можно настроить Webpack, чтобы он при сборке удалял пустые значения в файлах json?

Tags: javascript, json, webpack

У меня в проекте есть json файлы и я хочу, чтобы при сборке вебпаком пустые значения ("") в них удалялись

Comment: А что, так можно?

Comment: @Дмытрык я как-то писал `regex` фильтр, но для `gulp`, в принципе им можно удалить все, я им удалял блоки кода из зависимостей, вот он https://github.com/strangerintheq/gulp-task-builder/blob/master/src/regex.js

Comment: Наверное можно, но не нужно. Это может привести к ошибкам в будущем.